# Pytest CLI: how can i ignore test case by name?

Tags: python, command-line, pytest

User can run test cases like below

```
python /test/submit.py --pytest-args "test/cases/"
```

this will be run as

```
pytest.main("test/cases/")`
```

`submit.py` argparse parse argument expects `('--pytest-args', default='', type=str)`

`submit.py` is some module, where one of the def [like `initiate_test()`] will split *--pytest-args* by space, and runs pytest based on same split *--pytest-args*.

Now I want to pass `--pytest-args` in such a way that it ignore *test_name*.

But `-ignore` or `-k` is not doing what I expect.

Below is how I tried `-ignore` or `-k`.

`-ignore` seems like it is limited to directory & module.

```
python /test/submit.py --pytest-args "test/cases/ --ignore=test/cases/test.py::test_class::test_name"
```

while `-k=test_name` does selective run, but `-k!=test_name` did not do deselection.

```
`python /test/submit.py --pytest-args "test/cases/ -k!=test_name"`
```

Also I tried shell parameter like `a='-k not (test_name)'` with

```
python /test/submit.py --pytest-args "test/cases/ $a"
```

this does not work as there is space in *$a*.

Note: I don’t have access to *test.py* or *submit.py*, so I cannot use markers. So solution should be with respect to CLI.

Answer (score 7):

Use `python /test/submit.py --pytest-args "test/cases/ -k-test_name`

Note the the test to be skipped starts with a `-` when passing to `-k` argument.

One can also spell out the command line argument as `-k 'not test_name'`.

Comment: alternatively, I find `-k 'not test_name'` to be slightly more expressive

Comment: absolutely! I agree